# Help identifying this RF connector Icom FR4000

Tags: rf, connector, identification, coax

J1 is a coax push-in connector from an Icom FR4000 repeater. The gray wire is a thin piece of coax, unsure of the actual type (RG316?). Not a common connector but I've seen it before. Doesn't click in, just pressure fits in there.

I'm trying to make another pigtail so I don't have to cut the gray coax to add an N male connector on the other end. The manual recommends modifying the cable but I'd rather just make another one and keep the original intact to revert back.

[image]

Comment: There may even be a solid co-ax cable that has the same dimensions as the connection.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's a Taiko Denki TMP-S01X-B1 connector. A little hard to find in the US but eBay has some connectors and pigtails from the UK.